# How to add some styling for divs which contains error/valid input field?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I'm showing errors in the above fields, but I want to add styling near it, e.g., add some image as background into the containing div.

I'm adding it like this:

```
  $('input').change(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('valid')) {

  $(".field2").has(this).removeClass('bg2').addClass('bg1');
   }
  if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {

  $(".field2").has(this).removeClass('bg1').addClass('bg2');

   }
  })
```

and css:

```
.bg1 
  { 
  background-image: url('valid.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:320px 25px;
  }

 .bg2 
  {
   background-image: url('not_valid.png'); 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position:320px 25px;
  }
```

But now it working like this:

1. Firstly jQuery validation form appears[image]
2. Then, my bg adding ONLY on next input changing  and clicking out of the form[image]

I want to make background appears together with fields.

Can do it using simple jQuery events?
            **OR**

Should I add error labels for this? If so - please, supply an example of validation with form and labels WITHOUT error text if it is possible.

Comment: Instead of change you can use keyDown or keyUp and you write `$(input)` then write `$(this)` whats means of `$(this)` and you write `has()` and has() return true and false
your code is mistake

Comment: @SaeedPy, where is error ? I can't get... If input is invalid I'm adding class to its containing div.

Comment: Can you explain what you really want with illustrations? Give us a diagram on how you want to show the error message and the bg!

Comment: @Aravind, you see the first picture: errors on form appears, but red sign - not apeared. I want them appearing and hiding at the same moment. Is it clearer now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Saeed Py said, you should use keyup/keydown event instead of change. The problem with chance event is that it is triggered only when the **input element loose the focus**.

You could change it for either keydown/keyup/keypress to validate input on every key press. You could also add click event, in the case of a user pasting data with the mouse only.

I have made a [quite simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fYPwR/2/) demoing the difference between those 3 events. (It's kinda incomplete as I didn't use any field validation...).

As for your javascript, it should probably be more like this :

```
if ($(this).hasClass('valid')) {
  $(".field2").has(this).removeClass('bg2').addClass('bg1');
}
```

Should probably be written as

```
if ($(this).hasClass('valid')) {
  $(".field2").has($(this)).removeClass('bg2').addClass('bg1');
}
```

*this -> $(this)*

Of course, this depends on more markup then what you showed us. I'm assuming a div with a common class surrounding each input, as displayed in my jsfiddle.